# UDF function with library dependencies on MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I'm having a problem with a MySQL UDF function ([mychem.sourceforge.net](http://mychem.sourceforge.net)) that's dependent on a large library (openbabel.org) which is in turn plugin based. The problem is that the format plugins to openbabel doesn't seem to load in MySQL 5.1 and I suspect it might be due to the plugin_dir setting. I have set plugin_dir to /usr/lib/ which is the location for both libmychem.so and libopenbabel.so as well as the directory openbabel that contains the format plugins. Is there a way to turn off the plugin_dir restriction in MySQL (preferably without compiling MySQL from sources) so that I can test this hypothesis or do you have a different idea on what might cause the problem?
All this is done on Ubuntu 10.04 (but I had the same kind of problems on 8.04, where I managed to get it working after a lot of steps that I unfortunately have forgotten...)

I have turned off apparmor during testing and it doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of solved my problem, so here is kind of an answer to my question. It all boils down to problems with apparmour, at least for me. The problem was that I couldn't turn off the apparmor, doing so seems to leave MySQL in full-enforce mode or something. If I had apparmor in complain mode, it worked fine, and I could also modify the apparmor profile so to not complain about the specific directories (i.e. the OpenBabel shared directory).

/Fredrik